# Windows phone save data to file

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7

I've tried save data to file but I received following error
`Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream` in line `IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, storage);`

```
    public SaveFile(string path,string data)
    {
        var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, storage);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream);
        writer.Write(data);
    }
```

Comment: Did u take a look at the msdn sample? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xf96a1wz(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void SaveFile(string path, string data)
{
    using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
    {
        using (var fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(path + fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, storage))
        {
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(data);
                writer.Close();
            }
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```